# Better way to use jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent div containing 5 children (.item). Each child div is a progress point that can have three options: .past - .current - .future. The divs are in order (left to right) so if the middle div (3) has the class .current, the previous 2 should be past, and the 2 following that div should be future.

In my example I've used jQuery each to add the proper classes and it works. However, I am curious if there is a better, more concise, way to achieve this? (I'm sure there is!)

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/remix1201/uxgv62z9/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="series-set-options">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var flowStep = 3;

$(".series-set-options").children().each(function(i){
    if (flowStep > i){
        $(".series-set-options").children().eq(i).addClass("past");
    }
    if ( flowStep == i){
        $(".series-set-options").children().eq(i).addClass("current");
    }
    if (flowStep < i){
        $(".series-set-options").children().eq(i).addClass("future");
    }
});
```

Comment: There's always the option to do it with mostly CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/uxgv62z9/4/. It depends on your real use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `:eq()` and then `prevAll()` and `nextAll()` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/uxgv62z9/3/)

```js
$(".item:eq(2)").addClass('current').prevAll('.item').addClass('past');
$(".item:eq(2)").nextAll('.item').addClass('future');
```

Or as @Tushar suggested single-line [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ysro3rcy/1/)

```js
$(".item")
    .eq(flowStep)                         // flowStep = 2
    .addClass('current')                  // eq(2)
    .prevAll('.item').addClass('past')    // prevAll of eq(2)
    .end()                                // eq(2) end = go back to prev context
    .nextAll('.item').addClass('future'); // nextAll of eq(2)
```

Comment: **Single Line:** [`$(".item:eq(2)").addClass('current').prevAll().addClass('past').end().nextAll().addClass('future');`](https://jsfiddle.net/ysro3rcy/)

Answer (score 2):

A simple thing to improve your code

1. Use `$(this)` inside `each` to refer to the current element
2. Use `else if`

**Code:**

```
var flowStep = 3;

$(".series-set-options").children().each(function (i) {
    if (flowStep > i) {
        $(this).addClass("past");
    } else if (flowStep == i) {
        $(this).addClass("current");
    } else if (flowStep < i) {
        $(this).addClass("future");
    }
});
```

---

No need of using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/), You can use [`:lt`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) & [`:gt`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selectors.

```
$('.series-set-options .item:lt(' + flowStep + ')').addClass('past');
$('.series-set-options .item').eq(flowStep).addClass('current');
$('.series-set-options .item:gt(' + flowStep + ')').addClass('future');
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hc6z84xv/)

```js
var flowStep = 3;

$('.series-set-options .item:lt(' + flowStep + ')').addClass('past');
$('.series-set-options .item').eq(flowStep).addClass('current');
$('.series-set-options .item:gt(' + flowStep + ')').addClass('future');
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.past {
  background: gray;
}
.current {
  background: white;
}
.future {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="series-set-options">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the .each jQuery docs and see other parameter objects. In this case el would be your child item.

```
var flowStep = 3;
flowStep = flowStep - 1;

$(".series-set-options .item").each(function(i,el) {
  if (flowStep > i) {
    $(el).addClass("past");
  }
  if (flowStep == i) {
    $(el).addClass("current");
  }
  if (flowStep < i) {
   $(el).addClass("future");
  }
});
```